# p:dataTable rowEdit using Non AJAX approach

Tags: ajax, primefaces, jsf-2

In Primefaces, is it possible to do datatable row edit without using AJAX please?

I have a file attachment in the row which does not work in AJAX, hence trying to do rowedit without AJAX.

The below code works in AJAX way, but I am trying without AJAX

```
    <p:dataTable id="list" value="#{myBean.rows}" var="row"  editable="true">

    <p:column headerText="Edit" style="width:32px">
        <p:rowEditor />
    </p:column>


    <!-- Edit events  -->
    <p:ajax event="rowEdit" listener="#{myBean.editAction(row)}" update=":myForm:msgs" />
    <p:ajax event="rowEditCancel" listener="#{myBean.onRowCancel}" update=":myForm:msgs" />

</p:dataTable>
```

Comment: I'd see if I could put a 'add File' button in the row-editor that just opens a dialog that is outside this form, has its own form and allow selecting a file in that dialog AND uploading it. And on the rowEdit finish do something with that file (and on the 'cancel' to btw)

Comment: @Kukeltje Thanks, we want both to be in one transaction, hence its all in one action now.

Comment: Transaction where? Database? That is independent of the ui action(s). But why use cell editing then? Use a dialog... just as 'easy'